# How to type "navigate" parameters with Typescript in React Navigation V6?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am try to find how to correctly type `navigate` function using React Navigation V6 (from `useNavigation` hook). Especially when I want to use `navigate` in extracted/wrapper function.

```
const MyScreen = () => {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  const navigateTo = useCallback(
    (navigateOptions: Parameters<typeof navigate>[0]) => {
      // do something here before navigate
      navigate(navigateOptions); // error happen here
    },
    [navigate]
  );
}
```

I try to use `Parameters<typeof navigate>[0]` to get the first parameter type of navigate function (*note: `navigate` is an overloaded function in react-navigation type defs*), but it doesn't works. I got an typescript issue:

```
types.d.ts(147, 9): 'name' is declared here.
```

I am using @react-navigation/native@6.1.7

Comment: This library has beautiful doc regarding typescript typings https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript
it includes your case with ```useNavigation``` as well https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript

Comment: I already check this doc, but it's very basic...

Comment: well it covers your case...

Comment: It only cover how to type `useNavigation` and I have no problem to use `navigate` directly from this hook. My problem is how to type when `navigate` is passed as input of another function (here `navigateTo` use correctly typed `navigate` from hook). Or I missing something..